# Convert CSV to TSV format for Mongo Import

Tags: csv, command-line

I have this file csv file.

```
0161-1#CT-00#1;Others;0
0161-1#CT-01#1;Class;1
0161-1#CT-02#1;Property;2
0161-1#CT-03#1;Feature;3
0161-1#CT-04#1;Representation;4
0161-1#CT-05#1;Unit of Measure;5
0161-1#CT-06#1;Qualifier of Measure;6
0161-1#CT-07#1;Property Value;7
0161-1#CT-08#1;Currency;8
0161-1#CT-09#1;Data Type;9
```

When I run this command to convert csv with semicolon to tsv file:

`tr ";" "\t" < testing.csv` in the terminal on my Mac. It only prints out the text like this, it does not save the file.

```
0161-1#CT-00#1  Others  0
0161-1#CT-01#1  Class   1
0161-1#CT-02#1  Property    2
0161-1#CT-03#1  Feature 3
0161-1#CT-04#1  Representation  4
0161-1#CT-05#1  Unit of Measure 5
0161-1#CT-06#1  Qualifier of Measure    6
0161-1#CT-07#1  Property Value  7
0161-1#CT-08#1  Currency    8
0161-1#CT-09#1  Data Type   9%                                                                                                                                                                                                            ➜  eotd-cleaned
```

So it looks like it works, but the file is not save. What do I need to add on this command line to save it to this file or a new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many of the small unix text processing tools are designed to work in pipelines and it is assumed that the end-user will create a new file using redirection of output, ie.

```
tr ";" "\t" < testing.csv > testing.tsv
```

If you need/want to keep the same filename, and you're OK with deleting your original source file, then the safe thing to do is add a condtional `rm` command, like

```
tr ";" "\t" < testing.csv > testing.tsv && rm testing.csv
```

OR you can rename (`mv`) the file with

```
tr ";" "\t" < testing.csv > testing.tsv && mv testing.tsv testing.csv
```

The `&&` means "only execute the next bit if the previous command completed without error.

There are numerous other unix/linux text utilities that can make this substitution, the cleanest one being

```
sed -i 's/;/<t>/g' testing.csv
```

where you have replaced the `<t>` in the command with a real tab char, by pressing the Tab key on your keyboard.

As you're using a Mac, you'll need to specify a  backup filename as part of the `-i`, like

```
sed -i'' 's/;/<t>/g' testing.csv
```

The `''` means don't really create a backup file. You could do `sed -i.bak` for a real backup file.

Other solutions exist, so try searching here for "text substitutions in file".

IHTH